# Checkbox in table cell: checkbox is too small

Tags: html, css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table in which the last column of every row contains a checkbox. The problem is that those checkboxes are really tiny(almost invisible at some point) as long as the viewport is not unreasonably big.

The problem can be seen in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/93haq/

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th># Unit&eacute;</th>
                <th>Mod&egrave;le</th>
                <th>Ann&eacute;e</th>
                <th>Couleur</th>
                <th>Km</th>
                <th>Statut</th>
                <th>Succ.</th>
                <th>Co&ucirc;tant</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" class="carSelector" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" class="carSelector" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the checkboxes to always be at their biggest(like when it's not inside a table cell), like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/utvqh/

I tried to reduce the padding of the table cells but it doesn't help.

Anyone got an idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
td:last-of-type{
    width:50px;
}
```

Your table cell's width is not set, thus it resizes and resizes your input with it.

You can also use this:

```
.form-control{
    width:40px;
}
```

Use the actual width of your input element though and set the width of the class you want to set (if you'd prefer to use your "carSelector" class instead for setting the width)

Answer (score 0):

add to input width
like this:

```
style="width: 40px"
```

you can also declare it in CSS

Comment: You should **always** declare styles in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
tbody > tr > td:last-child { 
    padding: 0;
}
```

so the checkbox assumes the rest of the space rather than the padding of the parent `td`